# Is there a specific linguistic term for words like "Carolingian", "Ricardian" and so on?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

I'm talking about words used for the followers and eras of kings and queens.

They have a Latin origin. Is "Latinisation" enough, or is there something more precise? I've done a search, and haven't found anything.

**EDIT:** Sorry, my question was vague. While the responses below have given great answers, I'm primarily interested in whether or not there's a technical term for the component where Latin is used as the basis for the words.

(And as an aside, the pattern isn't consistent. For instance, we have "Elizabethan" and "Georgian" [not from Latin], but also "Jacobean" [from Latin].)

Comment: So are you asking about eponymous words or all words which came from Latin? The question really isn't clear.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the question. I'm asking about eponymous words that aren't a strict Latinisation (e.g. Josephus for Joseph), but that have a Latin root.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call them

***dynastic adjectives***

***heraldic adjectives***

:-)

Comment: Thanks for both the replies. I wonder if some linguist or historian somewhere has coined a private term for this Latin-for-royal-names thing.

Answer (score 2):

They can be called **eponymous adjectives**.

[Wikipedia has a long list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English).

There is no reason to limit them to Latin origins, and really, there's nothing Latin about Elizabethan or Georgian. English adjectives made from English names.

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I mean about Elizabethan and Georgian. I made an edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Those are "adjectives derived from proper nouns" and there's no specific term for them other than that, as far as I know.